# Delete all folders that don't have specific file type. Windows script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like a windows script that goes through a directory and deletes all folders that do not contain a *.pdf or *.txt file within it. How would I go about do this.

Comment: First, decide whether you're using batch scripts or the newer PowerShell.  You may need to do many searches or read books to decide.  Then learn how to write scripts in one of those two formats; again, you may need to do some reading.  **Then try to solve the problem yourself.**  If you get stuck, come back here and show your work (what you tried) and ask *specific questions*.  Don't expect people to write code for you.

Comment: While I appreciate your advice, this is something that has to get done today and I don't have time to learn it.  I've written some scripts in the past but have never really understood them, just modified someone else's script.  Plus, I've never been able to find a good resource for learning what all the a% and /r things mean.  I imagine this was no more than 3 lines so people wouldn't have a problem helping me out, but I could be wrong.  It could be much harder than I thought.

Comment: Here's a pretty good guide on `for` loops and other explanation: http://judago.webs.com/batchforloops.htm

Comment: The downvotes are because there is no visible effort to solve the problem. Nevertheless, this is an interesting question, therefore +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Provided the directory you want to search are on the C:\ drive, this code should do the trick: (Change C:\ to the directory you want to search)

```
@echo off
del List2.txt
set usb=%cd%
dir "C:\" /a:d /b /s > List.txt
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (List.txt) do (
cd "%%x"
if not exist *.pdf echo %%x >> "%usb%\List2.txt"
if not exist *.txt echo %%x >> "%usb%\List2.txt"
)
cd "%usb%"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%y in (List2.txt) do rd "%%y"
exit
```

But this will only work if all the folders are empty. If you want the file to empty the folders without txt files or pdf files change the `if not exist` lines to:

```
if not exist *.(pdf or txt) (
echo "%%x" >> "%usb%\List2.txt"
del "*.*"
)
```

Which will empty the folders ready for deletion.

### Brief explanation

`set usb=%cd%` 
This defines the variable usb as the directory it is currently in enabling it to be accessed later on in the program.

```
dir "C:\" /a:d /b /s > List.txt
```

This outputs every folder in the C:\ drive to a list. It should take some time because there are usually a lot of folders within the C:\ drive. By storing the folders in a list, they can be accessed later on.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (List.txt) do (
cd "%%x"
if not exist *.pdf echo %%x >> "%usb%\List2.txt"
if not exist *.txt echo %%x >> "%usb%\List2.txt"
)
```

This checks all the lines in the file "List.txt" and if there are no pdf files or txt files present, it logs the name in List2.txt.

```
cd "%usb%"
```

This changes the directory back to the original directory.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%y in (List2.txt) do rd "%%y"
```

For every line in List2.txt, it deletes the folders that were logged not to have either pdf files or txt files in them.

Hope this helps!

*Note: Tested*

Comment: two logical failures: 1) it will delete folders, that have a txt but no pdf or vice versa. 2) it will delete foldertrees if there is no pdf or txt in the uppermost folder, even if there are some files down below. And as you say: `rd` without parameters can only delete an empty folder without files or subfolders (well, this will correct failure 2 - sort of...)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set nocopyflag=0
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad') do (
 >nul 2>&1 dir /s "%%a\*.pdf" && set /a nocopyflag+=1
 >nul 2>&1 dir /s "%%a\*.txt  && set /a nocopyflag+=1
 if !nocopyflag! equ 0 (
  echo should be deleted: %%a
  REM rd /s /q %%a
 ) else (
  echo !nocopyflag! of the requested filetypes are present, do not delete: %%a
 )
) 
exit /b
```

check if the output is correct, if yes, remove the `REM` before the `rd`command